# Guitar makes humming sound, especially more when touching metal part of pickup switch that sticks out of the guitar

Tags: electric-guitar

I used a multimeter to test that everything is connected/grounded, at least I hope I did. It shows continuity when I touch all metal parts, so everything *seems* grounded. So I just don't get what can possibly be causing the weird buzzing especially when touching the metal stick of the pickup switch.

From what I understand, if touching metal parts makes noise go away, that is normal. But if touching metal parts makes noise worse, then theres a grounding issue. Touching any metal part on my guitar makes the noise lessen, except when I touch the metal part of the 5-way pickup switch lever (metal part). Not sure what else can be the issue if multimeter says everything is connected properly.

Please let me know what else I can do, maybe I'm missing something, thanks!

Comment: Maybe the problem is not on the guitar, but on the amplifier (or whatever the guitar is connected to).

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply! How can I test if that is an issue? I tested the wire that connects the guitar to the amp, all seems fine as well (followed youtube tutorials to check the wire, so hope that was right). How can I test that the amp is working right? Thanks!

Comment: There are a number of questions here that may be relevant to this problem. You can find (at least some of) them by using [this search](https://music.stackexchange.com/search?q=guitar+hum+pickup+is%3Aquestion)

Comment: @dannydav709 you could test it with another guitar (and cable).

Comment: @Aaron, ok, i will try that. I tried searching on google in general, and the answer is usually bad grounding, but I already tested with a multimeter, so it would probably be something else which I can't figure out.

Comment: @musicamante thank you. I did try another guitar, and it doesn't hum more just because i touch the switch, and in general, very little hum. its a cheaper guitar than the one im having a hard time with as well

Comment: @dannydav709 The search I linked to is a search on this site specifically. We've had many questions over the years about guitar hums, so there may be some helpful tips in among them.

Comment: @Aaron, ok will definitely check it out. Thanks so much!

Comment: It’s possible that a wire to the switch itself may be loose or bad. You’d have to open it up to see.

Comment: @EricO thank you for the reply. I have checked that all the wires to the switch are soldered properly, and even if there were a cold solder joint or something (hard to tell by eye), I checked for continuity, if that means anything. I am still getting a hum only when touching the switch lever. What is interesting is that there is no "continuity" sound when touching the switch lever to any other metal part in the guitar. And I tried this with another guitar as well.

Comment: ....... I don't even think the metal lever is connected to anything, since any other metal part of the switch (besides the lever), when checked for continuity with other metal parts, does make a sound through the multimeter.

So to summarize, the entire switch except for the lever that sticks out of the guitar front, has continuity to every other metal part of the guitar. Same story on another guitar I have, (which I never touched the insides of). So my guess is whatever hum I'm getting would fit under the category of "normal", although I'm really not sure, and am still trying to find out.